# Two column name same using join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been using `inner join` to join three tables. Now what i finally got is a joined table er where two column name are same and they have diffrent data. one contains locationname and another contain crop name. Now how do i access the locationname.

My production table is as follows:
[image]

My crops table is as follows:
[image]

MY location table is as follows:
[image]

My sql query is as follows:

```
  Select * from production AS cust 
    INNER JOIN location AS comp ON cust.location_id = comp.location_id
     INNER JOIN crops AS crop ON cust.crop_id=crop.crop_id 
    where cust.year_of_production =2004 AND crop.name="paddy"
```

The output after executing  the sql query is  as follows:
Here the there are two columnname as name . i want to access the name that contains taplejung . i donot want the column with name that contains paddy. How do i do that
[image: Here the there are two columnname as name . i want to access the name that contains taplejung . i donot want the column with name that contains paddy. How do i do that]

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *`, name all the columns you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the following could help:

```
Select comp.name,production_amount from production
 AS cust INNER JOIN location AS comp ON cust.location_id = comp.location_id 
INNER JOIN crops AS crop ON cust.crop_id=crop.crop_id
 where cust.year_of_production =2004 AND crop.name="paddy"
```

Answer (score 2):

First off `SELECT *` is horrible and [evil](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-%2a-is-evil); just select the columns you want

Second, your aliases are really weird. They have no relation to the table names which makes it difficult to read the query

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  c.name AS crop_name

FROM products AS p

JOIN location AS l
  ON l.location_id = p.location_id

JOIN crops AS c
  ON c.crop_id = p.crop_id
 AND c.name    = "paddy"

WHERE p.year_of_production = 2004
```

Here, we're selecting `p.*` which will select all fields on the `products` table. Next, we're selecting `c.name AS crop_name` which will add the `crops.name` field to your result *aliased as* `crop_name`.

This way you can work with `crop_name` as the field in your result.

---

Aside from that, I'm not sure which other fields you need from other tables, but you can modify your select to grab all the fields you want

```
SELECT p.*, c.name AS crop_name, l.name AS location_name, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have same column names in multiple tables, then you can specify it with table name.

For example,

`select table1.id, table2.id from table1, table2`

or you can use table alias

`select t1.id, t2.id from table1 t1, table2 t2`

and nothing to worry.

The same is applicable for any kind of joins. Nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of two ways you can do:

1. You can create a stored procedure and re-edit the column name on how you want it to look like.
2. For simple way, just replace

   SELECT *

with column of products.